# Sort a data.frame by number of non-zero elements in its columns

Tags: r

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:2, 10 * 10, replace = TRUE), 10, 10))
```

I would like to sort df in a way that the colum with the highest number of non-zero elements appears in `df[,1]`.

Bonus:
Within the groups of columns with equal non-zero-elements, a ordering by colsums would be nice (`df[,order(colSums(df),decreasing=T)]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code only needs to change by creating a logical matrix (`df != 0`) and then do the `colSums`

```
df[,order(colSums(df!= 0),decreasing=TRUE)]
```